# Old iPhones unable to find wifi nework

Tags: iphone, wifi, sim

My Dad has an iPhone 3g.

I have an original iPhone (2g)

Neither of them have the ability to find a wifi network anymore.

They have SIM cards in the, but the SIM cards are disabled (not activated by a carrier). Technically that should be unrelated, as they are different antennaes.

I am concerned Apple does this to all old phones to incentivise people to upgrade.

I've tried removing the SIM card as well, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

presumably, they both only can see 802.11b 2.4GHz & 20MHz bandwidth.

Can you check those are available on the network you're trying to connect to?

My old 3G [occasional iPod these days] can see my wifi if I don't trap it out with 'modern' tech.

Comment: Yes, those are the bandwidths I'm broadcasting at home =/ The 5Ghz signal I know it can't find